# Target system bash give me parameter error when I use `local -n`. How am I allowed to solve?

Tags: bash, scripting, bash-functions

I have a script that contains a `clearCnt` function that works correctly on my Linux system with bash version `GNU bash, version 4.3.48`, but doesn't works correctly on the Linux target system. The bash ( version: `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1) )` on the target system doesn't accept the command `local -n`.

The following code is an extract of the script that shall use the function `clearCnt` more times during the "main" script flow and shall use also a lot of arrays different from `hh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# clearCnt(src,dst)    
clearCnt()
{
local i=0
local -n src=$1
local -n dst=$2

while test ${src[$i]} != 'xxx'; do

    let dst[$i]=0
    echo ${src[$i]} ${dst[$i]}

    let i=i+1
done

return
}

hdc=0
hh={
GT5849503583053053
ST5849503583053063
MT6849503583053053
KT5849503583053053
xxx}

clearCnt hh hdc
exit
```

How am I allowed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`local -n` would define a name reference variable.

Update the `bash` on the target system to `bash-4.3` or newer (this is the release of the shell that introduced name references), or install that version of the shell elsewhere on the system and make your scripts use that instead of `/bin/bash`.

Note also that every single variable expansion in that code must be double quoted.  For example,

```
while test ${src[$i]} != 'xxx'; do
```

should be written

```
while test "${src[$i]}" != 'xxx'; do
```

or as

```
while [ "${src[$1]}" != 'xxx' ]; do
```

Comment: I cannot update the bash on the target system. It's a production system and we have security procedure that only administrator may do ... and I'm not he!

Comment: @SirJoBlack Good, then make the administrator do it. It's their job

Comment: Kusalananda,  Ah ah ah ah ah ... do you think that I've not tried this way? There are reasons why it is not as simple as it seems.

Comment: @SirJoBlack Are you telling me you have a system administrator that is _preventing_ you from carrying out your job?  What do the managers think about that?

Comment: There are reasons why it is not as simple as it seems. The manager and security manager think that we have to wait and try another way to test the system.

Comment: Go through whatever usual channels you have for getting software installed on the system and get them to install `bash-4.3` or newer elsewhere.  There is no need to replace `/bin/bash` with a newer version.  Once they have done so, point to that `bash` in your scripts' `#!`-line.   Alternatively, solve your problem in a language that is available on the machine.